# Customizing Component palette for GUI layout editor

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am a experienced developer who have worked extensively on delphi, Flex-Java web applications and have Just started learning Android application development almost a week ago. I am using ADT-bundle on win XP for this exercise.

When we are using GUI layout editor, we can see on left a component palette with textviews normal, medium, and Large. All three create a TextView with three different default attributes in layout xml file, which we can edit manually to add few extra properties.

I would like to add few extra properties to these default properties and create a different option on palette along with existing three options with custom icon for that. is it possible ? if yes How ?

Reason for this is to save time which is required  to add those extra properties manually after drag n drop of the textview component from palette to layout xml.

Similarly I have created custom components such as datepicker & TimePicker by extending TextView which is shown in palette by default and able to drag and drop from that. All is working fine but i would like to create a custom icon for those and set some default extra properties which will be created in layout xml as that component is dropped on layout from palette. Is it possible ? if yes How ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you require this:-

As you know you should have to use the CustomView For that you must write the class in that you should have to implement three constructor

```
public yourCustomView(Context context) {
this(context, null);
}

public yourCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public yourCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
 super(context, attrs, defStyle);
 // real work here
}
```

for setting extra property you should override ondraw() and onMeasure() method and have to provide extra properties method for it.

your custom view will display in 'Custom & Library view' option of palette.

try this example https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Views/ColorMixer/

hope this will help you.